# How to change Data Factory of Adapter by onClicking?

Tags: android, kotlin, onclick, adapter

I want to make an app like File Manager. I have already initial folders and I save them in Data Factory(FolderDataFactory, PrivateFolderDataFactory and CheckFolderDataFactory) by using KDelegateAdapter. What I want is to open folders by clicking them. In order to do this I am going to change adapter Data Factor by setting them. But I could not. I go from two ways.

The first way I used lambda method to handle click event. But I could not write it logically. (beneath I put code)
The second way I tried use override method in another class by passing global integer variable to indicate the state of which folder is clicked. It is working without errors, but not setting Data Factory to the adapter. (code included)

The First Way:

```
    //some code

    val clickTest: (FolderModel) -> Unit = {
           when {
               (it.title == "Личные документы") -> { adapterFolders.swapData(PrivateFolderDataFactory().generateFolderList()) 
//cannot resolve adapterFolders. Yes, it is obvious. But anyway how to pass //it?}
               (it.title == "Чеки") -> { adapterFolders.swapData(CheckFolderDataFactory().generateFolderList()) }
           } }

val adapterFolders = DiffUtilCompositeAdapter.Builder()
            .add(FolderDelegateAdapter(clickTest))
            .build()
        rv_folders.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 3)
        rv_folders.adapter = adapterFolders
        adapterFolders.swapData(FolderDataFactory().generateFolderList())
```

The Second Way:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    //some code

    var openFolder: Int = -1
    val folderState = FolderState()

    //some code

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    //some code

    val clickTest: (FolderModel) -> Unit = {
           when {
               (it.title == "Личные документы") -> { openFolder = 0 }
               (it.title == "Чеки") -> { openFolder = 1 }
           openFolder.toast(this)  //variable is changing
           } }

val adapterFolders = DiffUtilCompositeAdapter.Builder()
            .add(FolderDelegateAdapter(clickTest))
            .build()
        rv_folders.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 3)
        rv_folders.adapter = adapterFolders
        adapterFolders.swapData(FolderDataFactory().generateFolderList())

        folderState.folderState(openFolder, adapterFolders)

        //some code }
```

Comment: Both of your solutions can work. In your first solution, you need to make the `adapterFolders` a class member instead of a local variable. In the second solution, you need to create a setter method and call that instead of setting `openFolder` directly. Then in that setter method, call `swapData()` too.

Comment: @Mousa how I can make tge adaoterFolders a class member without defining it? I mean, first I should write that it contains my delegate adapter and it is set by recyclerView. Am I right?